# Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Tags: php, arrays

Recently I started using php v7.4 and got this error `Trying to access array offset on value of type int`

```
function getsize($size) {
    if ($size === null) return null;
    $last = strtolower($size{strlen($size)-1});
    $size = (int) $size;
    switch($last) {
        case 'g':
            $size *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $size *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $size *= 1024;
    }
    return $size;
}
```

how do I fix it **:'(**

Comment: I ran the the program I got no error but it always returned 0  as you are trying to convert string to int, it will always return 0. but changing this will fix this .  $size = strlen($size);
before switch change the line to this.

Comment: it works on v7.4 on local server but shows error on live server

Comment: try this method to get last char, I think the error is occurring there. So, try this: $last = substr($size, -1);

Answer (score 0):

no errors, just switched curly braces to brackets and it worked, (after setting $size = strlen($size); as Barno said)